# Best way to compare Objects on the top Level

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore

Hello guys im currently writing a Firebase Function where i have to compare two objects so i dont run into a infinite loop. My Object looks like this:

```
{
  id: string
  name: string
  coverURL: string
  year: string
  // part of another object so i minimize my document reads
  relatedItems: {
    id: {
      id: string
      name: string
      coverURL: string
    },
    id: ...
  }
}
```

I only want to do something in firestore if the value of id, name, coverURL or year changes. This way i can update the related Items of a object without running into an infinte loop. Currently im checking this with a function:

```
function isSame(oldItem: any, newItem: any): boolean {
    if((oldItem.id === newItem.id) && (oldItem.name === newItem.name) && (oldItem.coverURL === newItem.coverURL) && (oldItem.year && newItem.year)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to check if the objects are the same on the first level?

Comment: This: "_Is there a better way to check if the objects are the same on the first level?_" - not really. Some comparison will be required. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with what you have done.

Comment: I agree with @RandyCasburn, you can remove the unnecessary if else, by just returning the test and your function is probably the fastest possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look in google for "shallow equality" like here
https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/#3-shallow-equality

this link as some cool way of doing it too
https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/33-how-to-compare-2-objects/#es6-way-for-comparing-2-objects

but your solution is fine. if you would like an other way of writing it you can do

```
const isSame = (oldItem, newItem) => 
["id", "name", "coverURL", "year"].find(prop => oldItem[prop] !== newItem[prop]) == null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ill use some kind of function form ur first suggestion. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I would loop over the keys of the objects, so in this case, we can know for an `N` number of keys if the objects are the same or not, in this way you avoid writing tons of `ifs`.

you have to run over the old and new object because maybe they have the same length of keys but they have different keys.

```js
function isSame(oldItem: any, newItem: any): boolean {
  const keysOld = Object.keys(oldItem);
  const keysNew = Object.new(oldItem);

  // if the length of the keys are different, they are different
  if (keysOld.length !== keysNew.length) return false;

  // otherwise we can loop over them to see if the values are the same
  let same = true;
  
  // loop over the old object
  keysOld.forEach(k => {
    // avoid objects/arrays/etc
    if (typeof oldItem[k] === "object") return;

    if (oldItem[k] !== newItem[k]) {
      // if they are different we set the flag to false.
      same = false;
    }
  })
  
  // loop over the new object
  keysNew.forEach(k => {
    // avoid objects/arrays/etc
    if (typeof newItem[k] === "object") return;

    if (oldItem[k] !== newItem[k]) {
      // if they are different we set the flag to false.
      same = false;
    }
  })

  return same;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ill probably use this solution. But if i check the length of the items and also check if the keys of the old item are equal to the keys of the new item is it still necessary to check it the other way round?

Comment: yeah,think of `var a = { a: 1, b: {} }` and then `var b = { a: 1, b: 1}`
in the first iteration, you will exclude `a['b']` because it is an object (remeber the `typeof oldItem[k] === "object"`), so if you iterate just once, you will get that the objects are the same, but they arent, that is why you need to loop over it the second time but using the second object as reference.

Answer (score 0):

This: "*I only want to do something in firestore if the value of id, name, coverURL or year changes.*" is the base question.

If you are ready to explore a solution to *that* question, and are interested in taking a broader approach ("reactive") to this (and related issues), then consider another option.

This other option would be using a Proxy object. It provides a way to *watch for changes* rather than a parser function that is to *look for changes whether they occur or not*. That subtle difference is import for more complex objects.

The code is much more verbose. Perhaps the benefits are not apparent to you today, but maybe this will make an impact for you some time in the future.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for Proxy objects.

1. Create a handler (`mutationObserver`) to deal with (in this case) the `set`ting of a property on the proxied object

   - In this case that simply means firing a custom event that we can listen to
2. Create the proxy
3. Listen for the custom event to be fired

   - This means one of the watched properties has been `set` (changed)
4. Ensure you are operating on the proxy and not the real object.

```js
const doc = {
  id: 'string',
  name: 'string',
  coverURL: 'string',
  year: 'string',
  relatedItems: {
    id: {
      id: 'string',
      name: 'string',
      coverURL: 'string',
    }
  }
}
const mutationObserver = {
  set: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    const watched = ['id','name','year'];
    if (watched.includes(prop)) {
      document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('doc_change', {
        detail: {
          prop: prop
        }
      }));
    }
  }
}

const docProxy = new Proxy(doc, mutationObserver);

document.addEventListener('doc_change', (e) => {
  console.log('Change to: ', e.detail.prop);
});

docProxy.id = 'fred flintstone';
```

I hope you find this segway valuable.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! Whenever i got the time to handle this problem the correct way ill come back to this soluton :)